# getting the data in ajax after post request for php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, post

I have written a snippet in which an image is saved using ajax and php.

Here is the code,

Ajax:

```
$jq("#up").click(function() {
var canvasData = upcan.toDataURL("image/png");
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST",'testsave.php',false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
ajax.send(canvasData);  
});
```

Here up is the button that is clicked. canvasData has canvas context data in image format.

Php:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // Get the data
    $imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

    // Remove the headers (data:,) part.  
    // A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

    // Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

    //echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;
    $random_digit=rand(0000,9999);

    // Save file.  This example uses a hard coded filename for testing, 
    // but a real application can specify filename in POST variable
    $fp = fopen( 'canvas/canvas'.$random_digit.'.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

The image is saved successfully.Now i want to get the name of the saved image in ajax so that i can save it in a variable and use it for further. So how can I do that?

Comment: is the name not `'canvas'.$random_digit.'.png'` or am i misunderstanding this ?

Comment: Yes it is the name of image. I want it to get in ajax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// js

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(ajax.responseText);
}


// php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
     //...
     echo 'canvas/canvas'.$random_digit.'.png';
}
```

But in my opinion it is better to use jQuery ajax and its events.

Comment: I append,                                            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(ajax.responseText);
}                                                                   after ajax.send(canvasData);                                              But nothing happened!

Comment: Ok. it's done without using the function and just adding line alert(ajax.responseText); Thanks!

Comment: You have to add `ajax.onreadystatechange` before you call `send`. AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML - so it is ASYNCHRONOUS, you should wait for callback.